# Getting value on a custom webpart from another custom webpart on a page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-web-part

We have a SharePoint page which contains one visual webpart(vw1) which is displaying few values(id,name,address) on it. Now i need to add one more custom webpart(vw2) and which should get the value "name" from the vw1 webpart - so it can be displayed on vw2. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Its called Connecting Web Parts...

Have a look at:
[ConnectWeb Parts in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597538.aspx)
And
[SharePoint 2010 : Sharing data between Visual Web Parts](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2012/02/17/sharepoint-2010-sharing-data-between-visual-web-parts.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative since you are on Sharepoint Enterprise is to use a filter to pass data from VW1 to VW2.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-filter-web-parts-HA010033786.aspx